# Create and traverse a graph

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class with three similar methods. I can't consider which a pattern to use better for refactoring: template method, strategy or something else? I don't know. Can you help me?
Update: This code is a little exercise to be a better programmer. I'm going to add some algorithms, but it's not a production code. I would write good not smelled code for myself. I would have a beautiful code from this, if it's possible.
The main goal of the code : is creating a graph, breadth-first search and breadth-first traversing in graph. I've used a Cormen &al. algorithms from "Introduction to Algorithms" book. The method named `BreadthFirstSearch` is search. The method named `CleanVertex` changes color of vertex after search from black to white again. The last method named Path is for traversing the hole graph. All vertexes are traversed and their order are saved in a variable and return.

```
public class Graph
{

    public bool BreadthFirstSearch(int value)
    {
        if (StartingPoint == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var queue = new Queue<Vertex>();
        queue.Enqueue(StartingPoint);
        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
            if (vertex.Index == value)
            {
                CleanVertex();
                return true;
            }
            vertex.Color = Color.Black;
            for (int i = 0; i < vertex.Neighbours.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertexNeighbour = vertex.Neighbours[i];
                if (vertexNeighbour.Color == Color.White)
                {
                    vertexNeighbour.Color = Color.Grey;
                    queue.Enqueue(vertexNeighbour);
                }
            }
        }
        CleanVertex();
        return false;
    }

    private void CleanVertex()
    {
        if (StartingPoint == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        StartingPoint.Color = Color.White;
        var queue = new Queue<Vertex>();
        queue.Enqueue(StartingPoint);
        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = 0; i < vertex.Neighbours.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertexNeighbour = vertex.Neighbours[i];
                if (vertexNeighbour.Color != Color.White)
                {
                    vertexNeighbour.Color = Color.White;
                    queue.Enqueue(vertexNeighbour);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public string Path()
    {
        if (StartingPoint == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var queue = new Queue<Vertex>();
        queue.Enqueue(StartingPoint);
        var path = new StringBuilder();
        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
            path.Append($"{vertex.Index} ");
            vertex.Color = Color.Black;
            for (int i = 0; i < vertex.Neighbours.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertexNeighbour = vertex.Neighbours[i];
                if (vertexNeighbour.Color == Color.White)
                {
                    vertexNeighbour.Color = Color.Grey;
                    queue.Enqueue(vertexNeighbour);
                }
            }
        }

        return path.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. In the first revision of this question, code indentation is unusual & inconsistent. I found creating code blocks bracketing them with "~~~-lines" less accident-prone than prefixing additional blanks.

Comment: @Galina. Please try to explain what the code is used for? Are you planning to add more algorithms? Is it used often? Where it is used? All of that can influence the advice you will get

Comment: Well, they are similar, but they are very different as well.  They each return a different type and while the methods all sort of smell the same they also each have subtle differences.  I guess I'd want to know what the goal is.  Why are you worried about these routines?  Is this a class exercise or do you have a real-world specific goal here?

Comment: @greybeard I've tryed to correct.

Comment: @Gilad I've add an explanation in post, it's a simple home project for improoving my code skill

Comment: @FrankMerrow It's an exercise.

Comment: Others may disagree, but repeats like this appear in code from time to time.  To be sure, if the "constant code" is complex enough that you find yourself fixing bugs in it and having to patch those bugs in multiple places, then definitely refactoring of some kind is in order.  However, in this case the constant code is fairly simple and trying to factor it out will likely require some work that isn't worth in this case.

Comment: @FrankMerrow Thank you